# elements in XML parsing

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new in iphone Development, I don't know much about parsing. But I tried following code to get the distance element text. I am doing XMl parsing Of following link:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=30.9165904,75.8634752&destination=30.89314000,75.86938000&sensor=true

Please check my code which i have tried:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:
(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

 currentElement = [elementName copy];
if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"distance"])


{
       NSLog(@"ENTER IN distance");
      text = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

  {
       dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text,@"text",nil];
  }

    }

}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
  {
      if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"text"])
     {
        [dictionary setObject:text forKey:currentElement];
        [text appendString:string];
        NSLog(@"text....%@",text);
     }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:  
 (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

{

```
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"distance"])
{
    [distanparsingarray addObject:dictionary];

}
```

}

```
  By using above method I am getting the text both of distance and duration. But I want only distance text. Please tell me what I am doing wrong in above code.
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=30.9165904,75.8634752&destination=30.89314000,75.86938000&sensor=true

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage it by below way.
Add on BOOL variable at class level. Set it when you identify currentElement as distance.
Inside found characters append string to text only when above BOOL is true.
Make this BOOL as false in didEndElement when currentElement is not equal to distance.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:
(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{ 
     currentElement = [elementName copy];
     if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"distance"])
     {
         flag = TRUE; //created at class level.
         NSLog(@"ENTER IN distance");
         text = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];    
         {
              dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text,@"text",nil];
         }    
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
     if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"text"] && flag == TRUE)
     {
        [dictionary setObject:text forKey:currentElement];
        [text appendString:string];
        NSLog(@"text....%@",text);
     }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:  
 (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{  
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"distance"])
     {
         [distanparsingarray addObject:dictionary];
         flag = FALSE;
     }
}
```